# Read & Write File in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, while-loop

I managed to write into text file but something went wrong with my read file. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line, s;
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("hello.txt");
    for(int count = 0; count< 5; count++)
    {
        out_file << "Hello, World" << endl;
    }
    out_file.close();

    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open("hello.txt");
    if (in_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "File opening error. " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while(getline(in_file,line))
        {
            in_file >> s;
            cout << s << endl;
        }
    }
    in_file.close();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I managed to write 5 times of "Hello, World" into a text file. However, when the program runs, it only print out "Hello," for 4 times and the 5th row with "World". From my code, isn't it supposed to print out "Hello, World" for 5 times? Can somebody please point out where's the error?

Comment: `in_file >> s;` stops at the space.

Comment: Then how should I fix it? There is an error if I put getline(in_file,s) at there

Comment: `in_file >> s;` should be `line >> s;` although that would then give you a different bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  while(getline(in_file,line))
{
    in_file >> s;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

should be:

```
while(getline(in_file,line))
{
    cout <<line<< endl;
}
```

Since you read from the file into `line`, not `s`. so you should print contents inside `line`.

Answer (score 3):

You read the file doing Getline and using the operator>>

you should try

```
while(getline(in_file,line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
}
```